"TypeError: Failed to parse URL" error after switching to Middleware
I am using Next.js 14 app router, and creating the admin panel now.
For authentication, I decided to use Middleware. But, as soon as I started using it, I got:

[TypeError: Failed to parse URL from /api/v0/...]

I am using fetch method for making requests to my API (which is running on docker container on localhost:8000).
Assume I have a function to make requests to my backend, verify the access token is valid:
// AdminAuth.js file for requests to backend

const baseURL = "/api/v0/auth"

const tokenVerification = async acc_token => {
    const res = await fetch(`${baseURL}/token/verify`, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify(acc_token),
        credentials: "include",
    })

    if (!res.ok) {
        if (res.status === 401) {
            throw new Error("401")
        }
        throw new Error(`Error in token verification: ${res.statusText}`)
    }

    return res.json()
}

In Middleware, if I get the access_token from cookies and execute this:
// middleware.js
// ..

try{
    const res_token_verify = await AdminAuth.tokenVerification({
                token: acc_token,
            })
//..
}catch(err){
   console.log("maybe there was an error in verify =>>", err)
}

//..

I get this in terminal:

maybe there was an error in verify =>> [TypeError: Failed to parse URL from /api/v0/auth/token/verify]

What I did to solve the issue is I tried to hardcode baseUrl, and it works on my development machine. But, when I want to check the app, I am writing on my mobile device, I have to view it through the IP of the development machine in my LAN. So, the baseUrl is not correct when trying to work with the app that way.
How can I solve this problem?
This is also next.config.mjs file in the root dir of my project:
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    async rewrites() {
        return [
            {
                source: "/api/:path*",
                destination: "http://localhost:8000/api/:path*/",
            },
        ]
    },
}

export default nextConfig

Is it not working because I switched to Middleware?
